# Page size on iOS ARM64 returned by host_statistics64

Tags: ios, arm64

Right now, I use the data returned from `host_statistics64` and multiplying page counts by 4K to get the amount of memory in bytes. However, any call to get the system page size that I can think of returns 16K pages. Is there a call that will return the page size used by `host_statistics64`? Or is the page size fixed at 4K for that call?

Comment: `host_page_size`, `getpagesize` and `sysctl HW_PAGESIZE` all return 16K pages

Comment: I tested functions to get page size and described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33574804/751932).